# What's the fitting Java Runtime for files compiled by JDK 12.0.1?

Tags: java, jdk, jre

I have just updated my JDK to version 12.0.1.
Compiling works like a charm, but I cannot run the files anymore.

However, I couldn't find a fitting JRE (like JRE 12 or so).
As it seems, there is no JRE anymore, but everything is merged into the *Java SE*.
For that thing, I cannot find a download too; it always just gives me the JDK I already have.

So, how can I get the JDK-12-compiled files to run? Where can I get the JRE 12 or however what it's called now?

The JDK seems to be enough when I work within IntelliJ, but I cannot run the `java` command inside the cmd.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> The JDK seems to be enough when I work within IntelliJ, but I cannot run the java command inside the cmd.

In my experience `IntelliJ` uses it's own implementation to determine the location of the Java bin location.  This way you can have multiple instances of `Java Runtime Environment` installed and point to the version the project should use.

The only way you would be able to compile software is if you had the java runtime environment installed.  The `Java Runtime Environment (JRE)` has always been included in the `Java Development Kit (JDK)`.

> Where can I get the JRE 12 or however what it's called now?

You already have the `Java Runtime Environment` installed.  Everything that you needed was installed by the [Java SE Development Kit 12.0.1](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html).

> I couldn't find a fitting JRE (like JRE 12 or so).

The Oracle JDK license changed with the release of Java 10. The equivalent version of [Java SE Runtime Environment 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) is the [Java SE Development Kit 12.0.1](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html).

*The only reason you cannot run the java command inside a command prompt is due to a system variable issue.*  You likely are not pointing to the correct location within the JDK12 installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

In the [JDK 12 Readme](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-readme-5295984.html) you will find the following:

> Contents of the JDK
>
> ...
>
> Executables
>
> (In the bin/ subdirectory) An
> implementation of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). The JRE includes
> a Java Virtual Machine (JVM™), class libraries, and other files that
> support the execution of programs written in the Java programming
> language. This directory also includes tools and utilities that will
> help you develop, execute, debug, and document programs written in the
> Java programming language. For further information, see the tools
> documentation at
> https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/tools-and-command-reference.html

This means that once you download the JDK, you can have the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable point to the JDK folder, like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=\path\to\jdk-12
```

(Speaking about a Windows machine) You also need to put the `\bin` folder of the JDK as the first folder in the `Path` environment variable, like this:

```
Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;other;folders;here
```

Now you should be able to run `java.exe` from the `cmd`.

The info on how to set the environment variables I took from [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GDRAD/java.htm#BGBFJHAB).